# Angular routing/path change and scope issues

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to AngularJS and I'm facing these issues :

1. I want to have a list of items (movies) and when I click on the image or on the title I want the path to be like #/movie/id. For that I tried using ngRoute and also tried path but I have faced errors in both, can you guide me which one is suitable for my case and how can I use it?
2. As you can see in the HTML code, I am trying to draw a search box but right now when the API runs and returns data the whole content of the ng-app is being replaced with the movie list, should I create a new scope for just the content I want to change, if so how and where?

Here is my code:

```js
var movies = angular.module("movies", []);

movies.controller('movieController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json', {
        params: {
            limit : 16,
            country : 'us',
            apikey: 'rssd8z7pfw5t4nyd3cpszzzm',
            callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.movies = data.movies;
    });

});


//added ngroute
var app = angular.module('movies', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl:'/'}).
            when('/movie/:id', 
                {   
                    controller:UserView, 
                    templateUrl: function(params){ return '/moviessssssss/' + params.id; }
                }
            ).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    }
);
app.controller('UserView', function($scope) {
    $scope.movies = 'hereeeeeee!';
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="movies">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" hrf="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="ng-scope">
            Search : <input type="text" placeholder="filter for..." >
      </div>
      <div ng-view>
       {{ message }}
          <table ng-controller="movieController" class="ng-cloak">
                <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
                    <td><a ng-href="#movie" ><img ng-src="{{ movie.posters.thumbnail}}"/></a></td>
                    <td><a ng-href="#movie"  > {{ movie.title }} </a></td>
                </tr>
          </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please ask one question, not 2. And show us the code you tried, and tell us which problem you faced.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the links:

```
ng-href="{{'/#/movie/'+movie.id}}"
```

Then for getting the filter to work,

Put ng-model to your search box. And in your ng-repeat add `| filter: ng-modelname`

```js
var movies = angular.module("movies", []);

movies.controller('movieController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json', {
        params: {
            limit : 16,
            country : 'us',
            apikey: 'rssd8z7pfw5t4nyd3cpszzzm',
            callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.movies = data.movies;
        console.log($scope.movies);
    });

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="movies">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" hrf="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <div class="ng-scope">
            Search : <input type="text" placeholder="filter for..." ng-model="search">
      </div>
      <div ng-view>
       {{ message }}
          <table ng-controller="movieController" class="ng-cloak">
                <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:search">
                    <td><a ng-href="{{'/#/movie/'+movie.id}}" ><img ng-src="{{ movie.posters.thumbnail}}"/></a></td>
                    <td><a ng-href="{{'/#/movie/'+movie.id}}"  > {{ movie.title }} </a></td>
                </tr>
          </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: thank you @mohamerdrias the link now is changing to the format due to your advise , however the ngroute function is not , I edited the question and added the ng-route there .

Comment: Do you have separate url path in your ng-route for /movie/:id ?

Comment: Similar to this :  .when('/movie/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'single-movie-view.html',
    controller: 'moviecontroller'
  });

Comment: Yes, that's when you will go with templates. Now load separate template for movie list and when user selects one move to separate route and use the new template to show more details about the page. Now you may need to put the movie data api request inside service to share it with two controllers

Comment: before proceeding please check this error i am facing now though i included the ng-route module , and seems it does not even see the controller because nothing happens error:     Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: did you specify the dependency to be "ngRoute"?

Comment: Did you include angular-router.js file as well? Do you see any other errors in console

Comment: Gotcha.. You have initialized angular.module("movies",[]) in two places. Only in app.js need to initialize it using angular.module("movies",['ngRoute']) and in controller just get the module using angular.module("movies") no need to specify the dependency in the controller. Do include your app.js before controller.js

Comment: You need to have separate files for templates, services and controllers. Angular will load the files only on demand. It will take care of dependency

Comment: Then you can place it in your index. HTML instead of the templates file.

Comment: As like before you must mention a controller in body tag. So that it will respond.

Comment: can you please give it a try in the code we have 
plnkr.co/edit/cJXTZWqBUXNTPinf7AoV?p=preview

Comment: Hope that helps. Now i've MainAppController which will act as parent controller to all other controllers. Now the search is available across all the controllers.

Comment: In the second controller there is no filtering option. If you enter some text in search box in second controller and click back button, it will filter based on the search box.

Comment: The MainAppController acts as a parent controller. So when in other controllers if you refer to search keyword, it will refer to the maincontroller search variable

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

**[Click Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cJXTZWqBUXNTPinf7AoV?p=preview)** to see a live plunker example.

- in my example, **i used bootstrap**. remove if irrelevant
- there is a  **TODO** in my plunker - the server side movie filtering (when you type a something in the search field). **you need to read more about it in [developer.rottentomatoes.com](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search)**

---

This is the routing configuration i would define:

```
movies.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/movies', {
      templateUrl: 'movies.html',
      controller: 'MoviesController',
      resolve: {
        movies: function($http) {

          return $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json', {
            params: {
              limit: 16,
              country: 'us',
              apikey: 'rssd8z7pfw5t4nyd3cpszzzm',
              callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            }
          });

        }
      }
    })
    .when('/movies/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'movie.html',
      controller: 'MovieController',
      resolve: {
        movie: function($http, $route) {

          var id = $route.current.params.id;

          return $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/' + id + '.json', {
            params: {
              limit: 1,
              country: 'us',
              apikey: 'rssd8z7pfw5t4nyd3cpszzzm',
              callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
              q: id
            }
          });

        }
      }
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/movies'
    });

});
```

- *`/movies`* - a list of all movies
- *`/movies/<movie id>`* - a specific details about the movie

**NOTE** - i used [`resolve`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to pre-fetch the json data (this is optional)

---

### **index.html**

this is the main html code of your

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movies">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

---

### **movies.html**

the view of the movie list.

we get the **specific movie redirect** by `<a ng-href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}">`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search ..." ng-model="search" >
<hr>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:search">
      <td><a ng-href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}" ><img ng-src="{{ movie.posters.thumbnail}}"/></a></td>
      <td><a ng-href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}"> {{ movie.title }} </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### **movie.html**

the view of the specific movie

```
<img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ movie.posters.detailed}}"/>

<h3>{{movie.title}} <small>{{movie.year}}</small></h3>
<p>{{movie.synopsis}}</p>
<hr>

<a class="btn btn-default" href="#/movies">Back</a>

<hr>

<pre>{{movie | json}}</pre>
```

---

### **MoviesController**

the controller attached to the **`movies.html`** view

the `$scope.$watch('search',`  is required to query the server for each input change you make. **it's currently not working properly**; `rottentomatoes.com` ignoring the `q` param. you need to read more about it in [developer.rottentomatoes.com](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search)

```
movies.controller('MoviesController', function($scope, $http, movies) {

  $scope.search = '';

  $scope.$watch('search', function(newValue) {

    // TODO: you need to request again the movie list from the server. 
    // Read more about the API here:
    // http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search

    $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json', {
      params: {
        limit: 16,
        country: 'us',
        apikey: 'rssd8z7pfw5t4nyd3cpszzzm',
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        q: newValue
      },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })

    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.movies = data.movies;
    });

  });

  $scope.movies = movies.data.movies;

});
```

### **MovieController**

the controller attached to the **`movie.html`** view

```
movies.controller('MovieController', function($scope, movie) {

  $scope.movie = movie.data;

});
```

---

## Live example - http://plnkr.co/edit/cJXTZWqBUXNTPinf7AoV?p=preview

Comment: @Jane.L; use a service to pass the search string. see http://plnkr.co/edit/uqlOyTLfyaiRvze4tNLz?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

For your first question do this:

```
<td><a ng-href="#/movie/{{movie.id}}"> {{movie.title}} </a></td>
```